# Trunk method on cisco switch

Tags: cisco, switch, trunk

I knew about trunk concept but I don't know about connecting cables method.

If we have 8 switches to connect trunk cables across those 8 switches, any methods or rules?

Comment: What is the distance between the switches?

Comment: Is redundancy required? Link aggregation?

Comment: hello cown,Switchs are in same rack and different VLANs

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The most commonly used network topology is a Star topology. This is where all hosts are connected to a central switch or another network device. In the case of more switches, they should all be interconnected via trunk and all hosts should be equally divided between the switches.

If there's a larger distance between the switches, for instance, you have one on each floor in an office building, then they can still interconnect, but typically via fiber. Just remember, that if the same VLAN is used throughout a building you might run into problems with not enough IP addresses or the broadcast domain being too large, hence creating too much broadcast traffic, which eventually could disturb the users.

Star topology example drawing:

[image]

As you can see on the drawing, keep one switch as the middle of the star and then connect all the other switches to this one. If you need to interconnect via fiber, you might need to use two switches as the middle of the star topology.

Answer (score 0):

There is no changes in Configuration part when Configuring trunk port on switches whether switches are connected  with fiber cable or copper cable or any other topology they fallow.

There is no any specific rule or method, only thing need to be considered is if switches are connected  below 100 meters copper cable can be used example cat5e,cat6,cat6e. If switches are connected above 100 meters fiber cable need to be used .